# Can I get CMY and K from Python Pillow?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am using pillow to modify images. I need to convert RGB to CMYK. Pillow does the subtraction from 255 method and ignores black. I am currently using a floyd_steinberg method that plows through each  pixel and gets an average from neighbors. It works but is very slow. Is there a way to get Pillow to include black in the CMYK conversion? Is there possibly another python library that can do the job if Pillow will not perform the task?

Comment: There is no standardized conversion, it depends very much on the properties of the printer and inks you're using.

Comment: Thank you much. I am printing.  For scalability of ink strength, I will multiply and/or add to the RGB values. I will then clip to 255.

Comment: As a very rough start, I would use K=min(C,M,Y) then subtract K from each of those.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what the real issue is here. Is it that you can't print? Or that Pillow doesn't dither? Or that dithering is too slow? Or that PIL does CMY but you want CMYK? Also there are no images of what you have as input, nor of what you expect as a result, nor examples of your code...